# Heatmap generation

Tags: r, plot, visualization, heatmap

I have an Excel file with two different columns. One column have values ranging from 2 to 15 and other column have values ranging from positive to negative numbers.

I want to produce a heatmap in such a way that for first column each value should have a different color. Second column should be in the form of a gradient.

I tried using excel conditional formatting to do this.

But I want to know is there any way to do it in R?

Answer (score 4):

The R command `image()` takes a matrix and makes a heat-map from it. see the help page: `?image`. Also worth considering is the `heatmap` function, which is basically `image()` with some clustering applied. Below are two examples from these two plotting routines:

```
image(volcano,col = terrain.colors(30))
heatmap(volcano,col = terrain.colors(30))
```

Probably the easiest way to export your data from Excel to R is to save it as a .csv file (comma or tab-separated text file), and then import it using `read.table()`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add a legend to these graphs?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create an interactive heatmap in R using `plotly`:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(z = volcano, type = "heatmap")
```

[image]

More instructions [here](https://plot.ly/r/heatmaps/).